# Exploit Compilation Problem

Tags: linux, exploit, compiler, gcc

I am trying to compile the following exploit:
http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10613/

But get the following error: 
`local.c:12:22: fatal error: asm/page.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Answer (score 2):

Your exploit needs page.h header file.

 You must install [linux header](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders) package.

[asm/page.h is available in linux header package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/linux-headers/files/)

> linux-headers 3.11.6-1 File List : 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/numaq.h  
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/olpc.h 
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/olpc_ofw.h 
>   **usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/page.h** 
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/page_32.h 
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/page_32_types.h 
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/page_64.h 
>   usr/src/linux-3.11.6-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/asm/page_64_types.h 
> .
>   .
>   .